# NodeJS everyauth get access token

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, facebook-access-token, everyauth

I am trying to get the access_token for a user using the FB API + everyauth module for NodeJS, and then I will make serverside graph API requests using the Facebook_Graph_API module to actually make the requests (which requires an access token).

According to the everyauth page:

> Then, from within your views, you will have access to the following
>   helpers methods attached to the helper, `everyauth`:
>
> - `everyauth.loggedIn`
> - `everyauth.user` - the User document associated with the session
> - `everyauth.facebook` - The is equivalent to what is stored at `req.session.auth.facebook`,    so you can do things like ...
> - `everyauth.facebook.user` - returns the user json provided from the OAuth provider.
> - `everyauth.facebook.accessToken` - returns the access_token provided from the OAuth provider   for authorized API calls on behalf of the
>     user.
> - And you also get this pattern for other modules - e.g., `everyauth.twitter.user`,    `everyauth.github.user`, etc.

Within my .jade templates I can make the requests just fine:

```
- if (everyauth.facebook)
h3 Facebook User Data
p= JSON.stringify(everyauth.facebook.user)
p= 'facebook access token is '+ everyauth.facebook.accessToken
```

My question is, how can I fetch the access token from the server-side javascript? I noticed that within

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('home');
console.log(req.sessionStore.sessions.);
});
```

the req object does contain the access_token value but the corresponding JSON is very unwieldy to parse and not really practical for dozens of APIs. Is there any way I can simply  retrieve the access_token from the server using everyauth?

Hypothetically I could simply use a bit of AJAX and send everyauth.facebook.accessToken back to the server from the client but I feel like this is somewhat impractical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section answered your question:

https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/blob/master/README.md#accessing-the-user

Comment: yes, I can get the user from the app server just fine, but I was wondering how to get the access_token value without messing with the jade view

Comment: how about `req.session.auth.fb.accessToken`?

Comment: wow, for some reason i didn't catch that when parsing my json. thank you!